# How do I set a variable to equal every line in a txt file with for/f?

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

I have a ChatRoom batch file and it creates a text file were all the user inputs go into like this:
    Echo %User Input% >> C:\ChatterBox\Chat.txt

I have this so far:

```
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (C:\ChatterBox\Chat.txt) Do (
Set Chat=%%A
)
Echo %Chat%
```

That didn't work and it only gave me the first line of the text file, do you know how I can echo every line in this way?

Echo %Chat%

And have the output look like this?

```
"Line one"
"Line two"
"Line three"
"Line four"
```

Comment: Do you need to use a variable or do you just want it displayed?  A single variable has an 8K byte limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (chat.txt) do echo %%i
```

this will show you all lines in the chat.txt file

hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't solve the desire of setting the contents of the file to one variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're echoing the line after the loop ends, so you only get the *last* line printed (not the first). In order to use the lines within the loop, you must enable delayed variable expansion -- otherwise the variables get expanded when the loop is started rather than every iteration. Once you've enabled it, you use `!var!` instead of `%var%` to get the delayed expansion.

Here's how to do it:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (Chat.txt) Do (
Set Chat=%%A
Echo !Chat!
)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the desire of setting the contents of the file to one variable.

Comment: @Monacraft: It's not at all clear that the OP wants the variable to contain the entire contents of the file. I'm pretty sure they want to just assign one line at a time.

Comment: Thankyou, I think that the type command worked well enough for my purpose. @foxidrive

Answer (score 1):

You could also put all lines in a single variable that can be used outside of the loop:

```
set Chat=
set NL=^

::The above two blank lines are needed
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (chat.txt) do (
    set Chat=!Chat!!NL!%%a
    )
Echo %Chat%
```

And that should serve you well. It is important to note that instead of going through all the trouble to print every line just use: `type chat.txt`.

Mona.

Comment: Your code has a typo and the chat variable has no reference to %%a

Answer (score 0):

This will display the lines:

```
type "C:\ChatterBox\Chat.txt"
```